# Kann man "wir sind geschlossen" statt "wir haben geschlossen" sagen?

Tags: idiom

"Wir haben geschlossen" sagt man ja normalerweise um zu signalisieren, dass der Laden geschlossen ist.

Aber kann man stattdessen auch "Wir sind geschlossen" sagen oder ist es falsch?

**UPD.**

Ich vermute, es ist vielleicht Denglisch "We are closed".

Aber ich habe folgenden Gedankengang gehabt:

1. wir schließen => Präsens
2. wir haben geschlossen => Perfekt

und nach dem wir geschklossen haben

3. Wir sind geschlossen => Zustandspassiv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Wir sind geschlossen" ist unidiomatisch und wird daher von Muttersprachlern als falsch empfunden.

"Der Laden ist geschlossen" ist dagegen genauso möglich wie "Der Laden hat geschlossen". In der geschriebenen Sprache ist ersteres nach meinem Empfinden sogar vorzuziehen.

Comment: Was heißt unidiomatisch und heißt das "wird daher von Muttersprachlern als falsch empfunden.", dass es nur so empfunden wird, ist aber nicht falsch?

Comment: Unidiomatisch heißt: So sagt man das nicht. Und wenn man den Sprachgebrauch zum Maßstab nimmt (was man in der Regel tut), ist der Satz falsch (obwohl rein grammatikalisch korrekt gebildet).

Comment: Danke schön für deine Antwort und Erklärungen dazu in den Kommentaren

Comment: Heute sind die Läden geschlossen oder haben geschlossen. Was denn jetzt?

Answer (score 6):

"Wir sind geschlossen" kann auch in politischem oder hitorisch/militärischem Zusammenhang als "we are united" oder "we stand as one" ins Englische übersetzt werden. Etwa in "wir sind geschlossen einer Meinung". Eine Gesellschaft kann "geschlossen" sein, was bedeutet daß sie keine uneingeladenen Gäste duldet. Aber einem Nicht-Muttersprachler würde ich die Verwendung nicht empfehlen ohne vorher einen Rat einzuholen.

"Wir haben geschlossen" bedeutet, nun ja, zu spät :-)

Alles in allem würde ich sagen, nein, die beiden Wendungen sind nicht austauschbar, auch wenn sie manchmal vielleicht leichtfertig so verwendet werden.

Comment: *"Wir haben geschlossen" bedeutet, nun ja, zu spät :-)* - nicht zwangsläufig, es kann auch zu früh bedeuten, weil wir erst in 20 Minuten öffnen :-p

Comment: Nein, "wir haben geschlossen" bedeutet nur, dass der Laden nicht mehr zugänglich ist und nicht "nun ja, zu spät!" Absoluter Unsinn!